# asp.net - adding button with runatserver in back code

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I make this button

```
 resultsHtml.Append(" <button runat="server" ID='btnHelloWorld' OnClick='btnHelloWorld_Click' Text='Upd`ate label!' /> ");
```

run this

```
 protected void btnHelloWorld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblHelloWorld.Text = "Hello, world";
    }
```

In the same page?
They are both in the back code and the same page. The reason I put it in `resultsHtml.Append();` is because it's in the datatable

Comment: when you adding a new button within resultsHtml, does it generate the btnHelloWorld_Click button or not?

Comment: it generates a button, but it doesn't fire the onClick event. it doesnt even read the CSS

Answer (score 1):

Dont take whole button HTML script from database. Just take button name and onClick event name from database.

Then create button dynamically from code behind as follow:

```
    Button btnHelloWorld= new Button();
    btnHelloWorld.ID = "btnEdit";
    btnHelloWorld.Text = "Edit";
    btnHelloWorld.Click += new EventHandler(btnHelloWorld_Click);
    form1.Controls.Add(btnHelloWorld);
```

Comment: Actually it's not from the database, the data preceding the button is from the database. I just don't know how to cast it in the front end so every entry has that button.